# Setting the identifier of a UIBarButtonItem programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios, uibarbuttonitem, identifier

I have a `UIBarButtonItem` item in a xib file. I can set its identifier as play, pause, page curl etc in the xib file. Now how can I do that programmatically?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this should work (in viewDidLoad)

```
UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:systemItem target:tar action:act] autorelease];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButton = barButtonItem;
```

where systemItem is the `UIBarButtonSystemItem` type you want to use. full list of options [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIBarButtonSystemItem)

Comment: The point being, you can't change an existing one, you have to create a new one.

Comment: @jrturton i didnt get that part of the question but thats right. I guess you could create a new one with a different style using the target and action properties of the old if you needed to

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you right you want to switch between different system images with your button? I just had a similar case to switch between `Edit` and `Done`. Even though those are text labels the situation is pretty much the same.

The only way I managed to do this was to create two separate `UIBarButtonItem` instances in `viewDidLoad` in a way wattson12 describes above and assign the right one to `self.navigation.leftBarButton` when needed.

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue and I have read wattson12's answer then I solve another similar way. I do not know which is more effective.

```
//play button
```

@IBAction func startIt(sender: AnyObject) {

```
    startThrough();
```

};

//play button

func startThrough(){
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("updateTime"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true);

```
    let pauseButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Pause, target: self, action: "pauseIt");
    self.toolBarIt.items?.removeLast();
    self.toolBarIt.items?.append( pauseButton );

}
```

func pauseIt() {

```
    timer.invalidate();

    let play = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Play, target: self, action: "startThrough");
    self.toolBarIt.items?.removeLast();
    self.toolBarIt.items?.append( play );

}
```

Answer (score -3):

If you set the Identifier to "Custom" in IB you can at least change the title:

```
 -(IBAction)editList:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
    edit=!edit;
    [imageListTable setEditing:edit animated:NO];
    if(edit){
      [sender setStyle:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone];
      [sender setTitle:@"Done"];
    }else{
      [sender setStyle:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered];
      [sender setTitle:@"Edit"];
    }
 }
```

Comment: I actually found when running on a device that for some reason it works correctly this way around: 


`[self.tableView setEditing:!self.tableView.editing animated:YES];
    if (!self.tableView.editing) {
        sender.style = UIBarButtonSystemItemDone;
        sender.title = @"Edit";
    } else {
        sender.style = UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit;
        sender.title = @"Done";
    }`